# JUnit Installation fail on Linux

Tags: java, linux, junit

I try to install Junit 4.12 in my linux machine.

Here is the step I did:
1. Download the junit-4.12.jar from Github
2. Make a folder in my Desktop call junit and place the jar file inside this folder
3. Extract the jar file, now I got a folder called junit-4.12
4. export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
5. echo JUNIT_HOME=/home/zhengye1/Desktop/junit
6. export CLASSPATH=export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$JUNIT_HOME/junit-4.12.jar
7. Navigate to the folder called junit-4.12 in command line
8. Try to run `java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests`, Hit enter

And I got following error:

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.002
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.junit.tests.AllTests]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.tests.AllTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
    ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

I also run the `echo $CLASSPATH$` to verify my jar file, I got this
`:/home/zhengye1/Desktop/junit/junit4.jar`
Do I missing any steps?

Answer (score 2):

There is no `org.junit.tests.AllTests` within junit 4.12. I suspect you might mean `org.junit.runners.AllTests`

I would however recommend that instead of trying to manage your dependencies and build manually you look at using a buildtool such as [gradle](https://gradle.org/) or [maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Both are simple to get started with using and make life a lot lot easier

Comment: That is how I follow the instruction on Junit website, probably the old one.., but if I change to runners.AllTests, still whole bunch fail.. I want to try the instruction that Junit said because due to this issue I have currently... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29324063/cannot-run-junit-in-the-command-line

Answer (score 1):

The junit-4.12.jar JAR only contains the core classes for JUnit, not the tests of JUnit. That's why it can't find `org.junit.tests.AllTests` in the classpath.

Create your own tests in your project, and it should work fine.

I agree with with @beresfordt that you should use a build tool like gradle or maven. I also suggest using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ for development.